# My Program Only Processes One Line From The Input

Tags: c++

I'm doing a Caesar block cypher. The general steps to a solution are:

- Read your message into a large buffer or a string object.
- Either remove the spaces and punctuation or not (it's harder for the 
  Enemy to read if you do).
- Then count the chars in the message.
- Pick the first perfect square greater than the message length,
  allocate an array of char that size.
- Read the message into a square array of that size from left to right,
  top to bottom.
- Write the message out top to bottom, left to right, and you've
  encyphered it.

My Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <functional>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>
#include <locale>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int length = 0;

    cout << "Enter a string: ";

    string buffer;
    char buff[1024];

    while (getline(cin, buffer)) 
    {
        buffer.erase(remove_if(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), not1(ptr_fun(::isalnum))), buffer.end());
        break;
    }

    length = buffer.length();
    int squareNum = ceil(sqrt(length));

    strcpy(buff, buffer.c_str());

    char** block = new char*[squareNum];
    for(int i = 0; i < squareNum; ++i)
    block[i] = new char[squareNum];

    int count = 0 ;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < squareNum ; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0 ; j < squareNum ; j++)
        {
            block[i][j] = buff[count++];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0 ; i < squareNum ; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0 ; j < squareNum ; j++)
        {
            cout.put(block[j][i]) ;
        }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

For the most part, it works. The problem I get is when there's more than one line of input.

```
Ex. 1 
this is sample text suitable for a simulation of a diplomatic mission or a spy's instructions

Ex. 2
this is sample text suitable
for a simulation of a diplomatic
mission or a spy's instructions
```

Example 1 works and example 2 does not because there are multiple lines. I have a feeling it has to do with the while(getLine) function but I don't know exactly what to change.

Answer (score 0):

What you do in here:

```
while (getline(cin, buffer)) 
{
    buffer.erase(remove_if(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), not1(ptr_fun(::isalnum))), buffer.end());
    break;
}
```

is saving new line to buffer every time you use getline. I mean, each time there is `getline()` evoked your `buffer` is being replaced, not appended.

Try this:

```
string buffer = "";
string buff2;

// You need to provide some way to let the user stop the input
// e.g. ask him to declare number of lines, or what I recommend
// check for an empty line given, which is implemented below:

while (getline(cin, buff2)) 
    {
        // now pressing [enter] after the last input line stops the loop
        if (buff2.empty())
            break;

        buff2.erase(remove_if(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), not1(ptr_fun(::isalnum))), buffer.end());
        buffer += buff2;
    }
```

Comment: I didn't realize first, that the problem was not having an option to write more than one line. Now it should work.

Answer (score 0):

This "break" inside the "while" loop - it breaks the loop after the first "getline" call. That's why you get only one line.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should consider removing break after erase.